# No logging in external tomcat with spring boot application

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat, logging, logback

I am trying to log the spring boot applications logs to a separate directory(apps-archive ie ${catalina.base}/logs/apps-archive/log.log) in the external tomcat. After I start the server the log file is empty, and there are some logs in catalina.2021-04-04.log file about application is deployed and so...

In my spring boot application I have logback-spring.xml in src/main/resources as

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>

    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>
                %d [%thread] %-5level %-50logger{40} : %msg%n
            </pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <property name="LOG_PATH" value="${catalina.base}/logs/apps-archive"/>







    <appender name="SAVE-TO-FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">

        <file>${LOG_PATH}/log.log</file>

        <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
            <Pattern>
                %d [%thread] %-5level %-50logger{40} : %msg%n
            </Pattern>
        </encoder>

        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>
                ${LOG_PATH}/log_%d{dd-MM-yyyy}_%i.log
            </fileNamePattern>
            <maxFileSize>20MB</maxFileSize>
            <maxHistory>10</maxHistory>
            <totalSizeCap>400MB</totalSizeCap>
        </rollingPolicy>

    </appender>


    <springProfile name="dev">
        <root level="info">
            <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
            <appender-ref ref="SAVE-TO-FILE"/>
        </root>

        <!-- Hibernate loggers -->
        <logger level="DEBUG" name="org.hibernate"/>
        <logger level="INFO" name="com.commerzbank.eudsgvo"/>
        <logger level="DEBUG" name="org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql"/>
        <logger level="DEBUG" name="org.springframework"/>
    </springProfile>

</configuration>
```

I have no configuration for logging in application.properties file. Can anyone please suggest me why logs file is empty in apps-archive directory on server.

Comment: In your description you write ```${catalina.base}/log/apps-archive/log.log``` but in your xml-file you have ```${catalina.base}/logs/apps-archive``` i.e. with ```logs``` instead of ```log```.

Comment: Do you run with spring profile ```dev```, ref ```<springProfile name="dev">```. Can it be you should changes this to ```<springProfile name="default">```?

Comment: I used this <springProfile name="default">, Yes its working now, but its not following the RollingPolicy of file size 20MB, instead logs are increasing in a single file.

Answer (score 0):

The default profile spring boot apps run with is `default`.

Can you please change

```
<springProfile name="dev">
```

to

```
<springProfile name="default">
```

Regarding the issues with the RollingPolicy I don't have any ideas at the moment.